# iBeacon: how to distinguish between iBeacons with the same minor and major value

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware, uuid, ibeacon

[iBeacon specifications](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/Getting-Started-with-iBeacon.pdf) says:

> The UUID, major and minor values provide the identifying information
>   for the iBeacon.

**Major** and **minor** values are used to distinguish products or elements within a region. The Apple documentation is quiet clear on how to do it and the store example is quiet good.

However all this works well **only when** there is one element category per region (or sub-region) but it doesn't work well if we want the APP to be able to **distinguish among elements with the same minor and major within the same region**.

Is there **some other** unique identifier associated to an iBeacon that can be monitored/detected so that I can distinguish iBeacons with the same minor and major value?

---

**EDIT: Additional information**

To test this I have created two iBeacons with the same UUID and same major and minor value and then started monitoring for the iBeacons within the UUID that I specified.

The callback code that I have implemented for iBeacons ranged in the regions is the following:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {

    NSLog(@"Did range %lu beacon in region %@", (unsigned long)[beacons count], region.identifier);

    for (int i=0; i<[beacons count]; i++) {
        CLBeacon *beacon = [beacons objectAtIndex:i]; 
        // <- breakpoint!
        NSString *_cnt = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Number of beacons is : %lu and the current one %i is %f away from you %@",(unsigned long)[beacons count], i, beacon.accuracy, beacon.description];
        }
   }
```

When I **add a breakpoint** to the beacon line I see that both CLBeacon objects detected have the same information:

```
CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x17003d8e0> 74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935, major:20, minor:0, proximity:1 +/- 0.17m, rssi:-42)
CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x17003e840> 74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935, major:20, minor:0, proximity:2 +/- 0.28m, rssi:-47)
```

So as of now I am unable to distinguish among them unless I specify a major and minor value.

Here is the screenshot of the App I am using to configure the iBeacons (there are no other fields that I can configure):

[image]

**I wonder if within the blue tooth signal there is some sort of unique identifier that identifies each hardware.**

Answer (score 6):

**This is actually a common problem, and it is difficult to solve.**  While best practices usually say that different beacons should not share the same ProximityUUID/major/minor, **there are sometimes legitimate edge cases where multiple beacons are transmitting the same identifiers in the same place.**  (At Radius Networks, for example, we put default identifiers into our beacons, so if you order two of them they will initially have identical identifiers until you change them.)

Using CoreLocation APIs, two different beacons with the same identifiers will show up as two beacons in the `didRangeBeacons:InRegion:` callback.  This is because internally, iOS maintains uniqueness using the hardware address.  Unfortunately, **CoreLocation does not expose the hardware mac address or any other indication of which beacon with the same identifier is which.**

Using CoreBluetooth APIs in the foreground, you can get callbacks for each iBeacon seen.  And while you cannot get their hardware mac address, iOS does assign a unique identifier to each of them (probably based on a hash of the mac address) so you can tell them apart.  Unfortunately, iOS does not let you read the contents of the advertisement using CoreBluetooth so you can't read the iBeacon identifiers.  All you can really do is count how many different Bluetooth LE are around that might or might not be iBeacons.

It is possible to do some hacky tricks to try and correlate the information from CoreBluetooth and CoreLocation by using timestamps of when devices appeared and their RSSI readings.  But these tricks are not extremely reliable and prone to failure when many beacons are around.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive reply. I have checked CoreBluetooth and found the CBUUID class reference which does not mention that "iOS maintains uniqueness using the hardware address". Would you be able to share some document/reference so I can better understand which properties and classes I need to look at? Thank you!

Comment: PS: It would be great to get the CoreBluetooth data from a CLBeacon so then the correlation is easy. Is this possible?

Comment: No, unfortunately, you cannot get a [CBPeripheral](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/) object from  `CLBeacon` .  Correlating the two using the imperfect hacks I describe above is the best you can do.  Also, see this blog post I wrote about this:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Answer (score 3):

The - combination between UUID, major and minor should be unique. There shouldn't be two beacons with the same combination, this is the beacon identifier!

Comment: Thanks. So probably for the use case I am thinking of it is not ideal. Do you think the major and minor value can be overridden by an iOS app at configuration time? I am thinking that the user could associate each hardware to the APP and the APP itself creates a new minor and major value.. does this make sense? So the UUID is created at production time and is always the same but the major and minor are defined by the APP and in this way the combination is unique always.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement that you want "to be able to distinguish among elements with the same minor and major within the same region" doesn't make sense, as the combination of UUID, major and minor is the most specific you can get.

You can have multiple beacons with the same UUID/major/minor if you need to get greater geographical coverage, but these beacons will be indistinguishable from one-another.

How you apply meaning to major and minor values is entirely up to you - If you need to distinguish two locations then simply apply different minor values.

Comment: I have seen that some manufacturer (like Estimate) provide an SDK to override the major and minor value of an iBeacon. In this way an APP could uniquely identify each iBeacon when there is more than one with the same major/minor combination by overriding the major/minor values: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/200868188-How-do-I-modify-UUID-major-and-minor-values-

Comment: That is just the API that they provide to configure the beacon.  All beacons have some method to change their major and minor (and typically the UUID too) - this is how you give them the values you want them to have.  When you change the major/minor you aren't distinguishing between beacons with the same major/minor as such, you are just changing the beacon to have a different major/minor.